# Scrollview cannot scroll to bottom with keyboard in react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-scrollview

Scrollview scrolls to the bottom normally but when I touch the TextInput and the keyboard pops up, it scrolls only a very short distance and I am not able to look at the content below.

Just focus on android as of now

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

My code:

```
const Welcome = ({}) => {

  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}>
      <View style={{height: RFValue(33), backgroundColor: '#B1C59B'}} />
      <Main/>
    </View>
  );
};
```

where the Main component contains the scrollView

```
      const Main = () => {
         
          return (
         <ScrollView
              keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
              contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
          {CONTENT}
        </Scrollview>
        )
      }

     const styles = StyleSheet.create({
         container: {
         flexGrow: 1,
     },
```

Comment: Can you try wrapping your ScrollView in a `KeyboardAvoidingView`?

Comment: i tried and it works to some extent(not entirely) but it also changes my layout. I always avoid using that. Basically the scrollview wont fit inside the entire content of keyboardAvoidingView

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `flex:1` in your `container` style like

```
container:{
  flex: 1,
}
```

Comment: removing flexGrow and making it flex? then it doesn't scroll anymore not even without the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Above Scrollview take SafeAreaView and give SafeAreaView flex:1 then your problem must be solved.